# Blank pages shown by wamp server even after changing port number

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

When i run my wamp server and run localhost:80 in chrome browser, It is showing me blank page. Then i changed my port number to 84 in httpd.conf file. Even then it is showing blank page.

I tried with different port numbers(85, 86, 8084) and also stopped skype process which uses port 80.

Could any one suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'd likely get a 404 if your webserver were misconfigured. A *blank page* typically means a PHP error.

1. Check your error logs. You can find the log location in **httpd.conf**
2. Fix your PHP issue. The logs have the file and line number.

Comment: what the acceptance has to do with an answer? if you don't think he deserves your time just ignore the question, or put it as a comment

Comment: your votes will come from the peers more than from question originator. On the other hand I would not choose as accepted most of the answers this guy got.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi, ironic, I didn't take the time to look :)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You have to restart wamp server every time you change something in your config

**2)** Set everything back to default in wamp server or just re-install it

**3)** Open up skype, go to **Tools** -> **Options...**, Go to **Advanced** -> **Connection** And uncheck **Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections** -> **Save**

**4)** Launch WAMP again -> enjoy :)

Comment: I unchecked port 80, 443 options in skype. And while i am restarting my wamp it is even not starting its services. 

I worked before on play framework. Does it effect wamp server?

Comment: Try to click on the wamp server icon, and click on "restart all services"

Comment: i found the problem, it has started when i run it as administartor mode. But even now it is showing blank pages. what would be the reason? I even changed the port number to 83

Comment: it has nothing to do with port numbers... Create an index.php and write `echo "hello world";`

Comment: thanks for the advice.... but even it is not showing wamp server home page. it is just showing blank page and still it is loading state.

Comment: @user1156917 then just save everything (don't forget the databases) and re-install wamp, that's the only way ...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, here is the solution !
(there is more than one file to change in order to go to different port)

**Cause :**

Another program (Skype but not only) is using the port80 (which is by default the one used by wamp).
You can see it typing the following command "netstat -ano" and looking what is on "localadress 0.0.0.0.80", if you want to see the concerned program open, note the number at the end of the line (4 for example), then open taskmanager, services, and see who is on PID 4.

**Solution :**

Let's **change wamp port to 81** !

[Change wamp port from 80 to 81](http://xfloyd.net/blog/?p=515)